# Update Trigger with inner join construction

Tags: sql, triggers, inner-join

i'm not sure is it all correct
i'm wanreding about if construcion and inner join in where

```
USE x;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT typ1
    FROM db.y
    WHERE typ1 ='wartosc' and typ2 = 'wartosc')

DROP TRIGGER triggername;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
ON [db.jakiasbaza][y.typ]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
declare @zmienna1   
declare @zmienna2 varchar(20)
IF (UPDATE (zmienna1))
    SET zmienna1= 'cos1'
ELSEIF
    SET zmienna1= 'cos2'
END IF;
BEGIN
UPDATE x.typ1
SET @zmienna1 = 'jakaswartosc'
WHERE x INNER JOIN y
    ON x.typ1 = y.typ1
    WHERE (x.typ1 = 'wartosc'and x.typ2 = 'wartosc' 
END;
GO
```

Thx

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sort of looks like SQL Server.  The correct syntax for an update with a join is something like this in your case:

```
UPDATE x
    SET zmienna1 = (CASE WHEN UPDATE(zmienna1) THEN 'jakaswartosc' ELSE zmienna1 END),
        zmienna2 = (CASE WHEN UPDATE(zmienna1) THEN zmienna2 ELSE 'jakaswartosc' END)
    FROM x INNER JOIN
         y
         ON x.typ1 = y.typ1
    WHERE x.typ1 = 'wartosc' and x.typ2 = 'wartosc' ;
```

Note that you cannot specify the target column (or any other column) using a variable -- hence the use of the `case` statement.

Alternatively, you could have two update statements:

```
IF (UPDATE (zmienna1))
    UPDATE x
        SET cos1 = 'jakaswartosc'
        FROM x INNER JOIN
             y
             ON x.typ1 = y.typ1
        WHERE x.typ1 = 'wartosc' and x.typ2 = 'wartosc' ;
ELSE 
    UPDATE x
        SET cos2 = 'jakaswartosc'
        FROM x INNER JOIN
             y
             ON x.typ1 = y.typ1
        WHERE x.typ1 = 'wartosc' and x.typ2 = 'wartosc' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

so it shloud look like this, 
but if i want to add more variables
like declare @zmienna2, @zmienna3
and just set this into specyfic value
i can be like this :

```
USE x;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT typ1
    FROM db.y
    WHERE typ1 ='wartosc' and typ2 = 'wartosc')

DROP TRIGGER triggername;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
ON [db.sampledbname][y.typ]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
declare @zmienna1 varchar(20)   
declare @zmienna2 varchar(20)
declare @zmienna3 varchar(20)
IF (UPDATE (zmienna1))
    UPDATE x
        SET cos1 = 'valuex'
        FROM x INNER JOIN y
             ON x.type1 = y.type1
        WHERE x.type1 = 'something1' and x.type2 = 'something2' ;
ELSE 
    UPDATE x
        SET cos2 = 'valuey'
        FROM x INNER JOIN y
             ON x.type1 = y.type1
        WHERE x.type1 = 'something1' and x.type2 = 'something2' ;
END IF;
BEGIN
SET @zmienna2 = 'value1'
SET @zmienna3 = 'value2'
END;
GO
```

?